# Describe all the homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ to itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

This is problem 1.49 Of Rotman´s Introduction to theory of groups

> Describe all the homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ to itself. Which of them are isomorphisms?

Knowing that there are $12!$ bijections between $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ and itself, I tried by defining $f:\Bbb{Z}_{12} \to \Bbb{Z}_{12}$ trying to find some restriction by imposing that $f$ should be a homomorphism but arrived to nothing. Any  hint?

Comment: Hint: a homomorphism is uniquely defined on a generator.

Comment: More explicit - but less general - than @Corvus was:  $f(n) = n \cdot f(1)$ if $f$ is a homomorphism. (hint for second part, given previous) For $f$ to be an iso, what must be true about $f(1)$?

Comment: Actually, @Corvus's hint is better than mine, especially in light of what must be true about $f(1)$ for $f$ to be an iso...